# selenium webdriver download file from a button element

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I need to download a link from this page and save the file but I can't use the .get_attribute("href").
I know that I need to click on the button but I can't find how to from the snippet code concerning the button. I'm lost... Please help me

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;" action="/monats-neuzulassungen?tx_ivmmonthlystatistics_webtable%5Baction%5D=excelExport&amp;tx_ivmmonthlystatistics_webtable%5Bcontroller%5D=Admission&amp;cHash=21a1fff4bef46b82acfae82df1803b52" method="post">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="tx_ivmmonthlystatistics_webtable[__referrer][@extension]" value="Ivmmonthlystatistics">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_ivmmonthlystatistics_webtable[__referrer][@vendor]" value="Monsun">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_ivmmonthlystatistics_webtable[__referrer][@controller]" value="Admission">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_ivmmonthlystatistics_webtable[__referrer][@action]" value="statistic">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_ivmmonthlystatistics_webtable[__referrer][arguments]" value="YTowOnt9ed1d05243fc7ad17bd60324ad4fe5c5c92491392">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_ivmmonthlystatistics_webtable[__referrer][@request]" value="a:4:{s:10:&quot;@extension&quot;;s:20:&quot;Ivmmonthlystatistics&quot;;s:11:&quot;@controller&quot;;s:9:&quot;Admission&quot;;s:7:&quot;@action&quot;;s:9:&quot;statistic&quot;;s:7:&quot;@vendor&quot;;s:6:&quot;Monsun&quot;;}f94e8514f1eaa3c43c7d46ac491c3488a8c401b2">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_ivmmonthlystatistics_webtable[__trustedProperties]" value="a:1:{s:10:&quot;filterJson&quot;;i:1;}987f554a7151080f44fd21bd5ae43d13f4a30f20">
</div>

                <input type="hidden" name="tx_ivmmonthlystatistics_webtable[filterJson]" value="{&quot;triumphareaId&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;triumphSorting&quot;:&quot;ar-na-no&quot;,&quot;triumphTraderList&quot;:[],&quot;userDistrictsName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;customFilterName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;regionUserdefinedList&quot;:0,&quot;regionDealerregionList&quot;:0,&quot;piaggioModelList&quot;:0,&quot;firstColumnType&quot;:&quot;nonZeroByFilter&quot;,&quot;myFilterSelected&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;evaluationType&quot;:&quot;filter-classic&quot;,&quot;vehicleGroup&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;5&quot;:&quot;5&quot;,&quot;6&quot;:&quot;6&quot;},&quot;capacityClass&quot;:[],&quot;classicStatisticForType&quot;:&quot;branding&quot;,&quot;classicTableType&quot;:&quot;current-hit&quot;,&quot;engineType&quot;:[],&quot;gender&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;4&quot;:&quot;4&quot;},&quot;manufacturer&quot;:[],&quot;advFormTable&quot;:0,&quot;advFormColumn&quot;:0,&quot;advFormRow&quot;:0,&quot;regionType&quot;:1,&quot;regionState&quot;:[],&quot;regionDistrict&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;yearFirstRegistration&quot;:[],&quot;vehicleSegment&quot;:1,&quot;vehicleSegmentOld&quot;:[],&quot;vehicleSegmentNew&quot;:[&quot;0&quot;],&quot;timerType&quot;:&quot;currentYear&quot;,&quot;timerCurrentMonth&quot;:10,&quot;timerLastMonth&quot;:9,&quot;timerCurrentYear&quot;:2022,&quot;timerLastYear&quot;:2021,&quot;timerBookYear&quot;:2019,&quot;timerBookMonth&quot;:&quot;07&quot;,&quot;timerBookLastYear&quot;:0,&quot;timerBookLastMonth&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;timerBookRangeStartYear&quot;:2021,&quot;timerBookRangeStartMonth&quot;:&quot;01&quot;,&quot;timerBookRangeStopYear&quot;:2021,&quot;timerBookRangeStopMonth&quot;:&quot;01&quot;,&quot;timerLastTwelveMonthMonth&quot;:&quot;01&quot;,&quot;timerLastTwelveMonthYear&quot;:0,&quot;timerSelectedYear&quot;:2019,&quot;timerYearForSelectedYear&quot;:2021,&quot;timerSelectedMonth&quot;:&quot;03&quot;,&quot;timerRangeStart&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;timerRangeStop&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;timerLimitStart&quot;:null,&quot;timerLimitStop&quot;:null,&quot;typeOfInformation&quot;:1,&quot;customfilter&quot;:29,&quot;yamlSwitchTableInfo&quot;:&quot;&quot;}">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary d-inline-flex align-items-center float-right" id="monthlyivmstatistic-user-myfilter" type="submit" name="" value="">
                        <svg width="20" height="20" class="mr-2">
                            <use xlink:href="#download"></use>
                        </svg>
                        
                            Export als .xls
                        
                    </button>
            </form>
```

Comment: what have you tried? what parts of the button element have you tried clicking?

Comment: I tried accessing the elment using the action but it threw an error. Then I tried the ID but it did not work either